# Am having C DLL send parameters to c dll from C#

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

I am trying to call a C dll  from C#.The function which Iam calling is declared in the dll as given below

```
int WINAPI checkConnectivity(char *fqdn, int port);
```

i want to send parameter "www.google.com" to char *fqdn

8080 to int port as a parameter through C#

```
[DllImport(@"E:\\ASip.dll")]      
public static extern int checkConnectivity(StringBuilder fqdn, int port);

private  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder colourstring = new StringBuilder("www.google.com");
    int nb = checkConnectivity(colourstring, 80);
}
```

Comment: Take a look to DllImportAttribute (or Google about similar questions).

Comment: i already tried lot of websites but am getting error i imported dll correctly but i send paramater it gets error

Comment: Share what you tried! It'll help to **hihghlight** error

Comment: If you already have an attempt, you should show that code here. We might be able to figure out what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that the text parameter is an input parameter. In which case the correct declaration is:

```
[DllImport(@"E:\ASip.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]      
public static extern int checkConnectivity(string fqdn, int port);
```

Call the function like this:

```
int nb = checkConnectivity("www.google.com", 80);
```

Changing from `StringBuilder` to `string` should not have any influence on the outcome of your function call, it is just more correct. The other change I made was to remove the spurious `\\` which should be `\` in a verbatim string.

If you still do not succeed then the issue is not related to the signature of the function.